# Looking for a DID (or VoIP-in) number in the Beijing area

Tags: voip

I am looking for an option to have a Direct-Inwards-Dialing option as provided by Skype or Gizmo5, but in the Beijing area (China). Both these providers do not have such an option. I do not search for a computer only solution like QQ, but a real way to use PSTN 2 VoIP.

Comment: We tried to get this in Hong Kong, and we were required to ahve a "Local Presence" (i.e. a physical office) before we could get a number allocated. There are companies that will be your "Local Presence" for you if you run into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these guys offer the service:

https://www.terrasip.com/xoshop/terrasip_did_new2.php?language=en&t_country=gb